# Snowflake categorization changes over time

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Im trying to come up with a Snowflake query that from the same location will return the changes in sales from when a location had a category during period 1 and then another column with the category it had on period 2 and its sales, ideally i'd like to have a crosstab that can define what the sales where from locations with category a on 2022 and where is the new categorization on 2023. as in the example below, of 45 sales on locations with category a those same locations are now categorized a b and c with sales of 10 remaining on a, 15 on b and 20 on c.

| Category | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | 15 | 20 |
| b | 0 | 50 | 20 |
| c | 1 | 2 | 100 |

the way Im currently working on is with a query similar to this

```
Select  Location,   
Case When SaleDate=2022 Then Category as "Cat 2022",
Sum(Case When SaleDate=2022 Then 1 Else 0 End) as "Sales2022",
Case When SaleDate=2023 Then Category as "Cat 2023",
Sum(Case When SaleDate=2023 Then 1 Else 0 End) as "Sales2023"
From A Where SaleDate between 2022 and 2023 
Group by  1,2,4
```

however the result has been Loc1 with its 2022 sales in row 1, 2023 on row2 instead of having them both on the same row

| Location | Cat2022 | Sales2022 | Cat2023 | Sales2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 10 | null | null |
| 1 | null | null | b | 15 |

Do you see what I have been doing wrong? i would like that for the same location both periods are on the same line (ideally a crosstable).
Thanks!

Comment: Hi - this may just be me but I've read your question a number of times and I still have no idea what you are asking or what you are trying to achieve; for example you've provided 2 completely different tables and I have no idea if they are source data, what you are trying to achieve, why they are different, etc. Please can you try and clarify by providing 1) the DDL for the source table(s) 2) sample data for those tables 3) the result you are trying to achieve - based on the sample data 4) a clearly explained list of the business rules being applied to create the result from the source.